# How to draw a Google chart when I click an option on a <select> drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Suppose I have a `<select>` drop down menu here:

```
<select id="menu">
    <option>livejournal</option>
    <option>librarybooks</option>
    <option>sunspots</option>
</select>
```

And I tried to link it to a Google Chart API so when I click the options in the menu it will draw the correspondent charts(to replace the existing one) on the page.

I uses `object.onchange` to implement this, but seems `chart.draw` won't able to draw a chart, what else am I missing here?

```
//Dropdown Menu Selection
document.getElementById("menu").onchange = function () {
    //livejournal
    if(this.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert("Default");
    }
    //librarybooks
    if(this.selectedIndex == 1){
        alert("librarybooks");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Digit', 'Benford', 'Librarybooks'],
            ['1', 1000, 200],
            ['2', 1170, 760],
            ['3', 660, 100],
            ['4', 1030, 300],
            ['5', 1030, 140],
            ['6', 1030, 640],
            ['7', 1030, 240],
            ['8', 1030, 440],
            ['9', 1030, 840]
        ]);;
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
    //sunspots
    if(this.selectedIndex == 2){
        alert("Sunspots");
    }
}
```

And this is the original API I am using:

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Link to the Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't see where `chart` is created --> `var chart = new google.charts.Bar...`

or the definition for `options` --> `var options = {...`

recommend using a `switch` statement to determine the value of the menu

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
    var dataDefault = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
        ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
        ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
        ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
        ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]);

    var dataLibraryBooks = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Digit', 'Benford', 'Librarybooks'],
        ['1', 1000, 200],
        ['2', 1170, 760],
        ['3', 660, 100],
        ['4', 1030, 300],
        ['5', 1030, 140],
        ['6', 1030, 640],
        ['7', 1030, 240],
        ['8', 1030, 440],
        ['9', 1030, 840]
    ]);;

    var dataSunspots = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['x', 'y'],
        ['A', 10],
        ['B', 30],
        ['C', 50],
        ['D', 70],
        ['E', 90]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Bar Chart'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    menu.addEventListener('change', drawChart, false);

    drawChart();
    function drawChart() {
      switch (menu.selectedIndex) {
        case 1:
          console.log('librarybooks');
          chart.draw(dataLibraryBooks, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
          break;

        case 2:
          console.log('Sunspots');
          chart.draw(dataSunspots, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
          break;

        default:
          console.log('default');
          chart.draw(dataDefault, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<select id="menu">
  <option selected>livejournal</option>
  <option>librarybooks</option>
  <option>sunspots</option>
</select>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not called:  `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
 
      function drawgraph(index){  
 if(index==0){
   document.getElementById('livejournal');
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart('livejournal'));
 }
 if(index==1){
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart('librarybooks'));
 }
if(index==2){
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart('sunspots'));
 }
      }
      function drawChart(divId) {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          },
          bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById(divId));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="menu" onchange=drawgraph(this.selectedIndex)>
    <option>livejournal</option>
    <option>librarybooks</option>
    <option>sunspots</option>
</select>
    
    <div id="livejournal" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="librarybooks" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="sunspots" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```